# Modifying default in StreamGear "main" stream

Tags: python, video-streaming

I use StreamGear from vidgear python library to generate a video stream from a sequence of images (calling `stream` method on each image).
Output is a stream with the same resolution as the input image.
I want to modify default ffmpeg parameters so that output video resolution is different.

[Documentation](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/streamgear/params/#b-ffmpeg-parameters) said we can use ffmpeg parameters to alter default params. I tried to use `"-video_size": "320x240",` in stream_params, but if it effectively append this to the ffmpeg params, it does not replace the default one.

I could achieve the modification resolution by modifying the image with opencv.
`streamer.stream(cv2.resize(cv_image, (320, 240)))`, but this is only half satisfactory as I guess I will have problem if I want to modify a full profile (resolution, bitrate, or whatever).

Note I do not want multi-stream (which works fine).

Here is my code :

```py
def __create_streamer(self, ):
    stream_params = {
        "-input_framerate": 30,
        "-livestream": True,
        "-hls_init_time": 1,
        "-hls_time": 1,  # video segment duration, in second
        "-vcodec": "libx265",
        "-clear_prev_assets": True,  # erase previous data
        "-video_size": "320x240",  # ignored by ffmpeg which is called with '-video_size 1920x1080'
    }

    # ... blabla
    output = "my_video_stream.m3u8"
    self.video_streamer = StreamGear(output=output, format = "hls", **stream_params)

def __camera_sub_callback(self, msg):
    # method called each time an image is received (-> ROS2 node, image is in message)
    # image have dimensions 1920x1080

    if self.video_streamer is None:
        self.__create_streamer()

    # self.bridge = CvBridge() in the cstr
    # turn msg to an img - np.array
    cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, desired_encoding='bgr8')

    # this works
    self.video_streamer.stream(cv2.resize(cv_image, (320, 240)))
    
    # but i'd like to keep
    # self.video_streamer.stream(cv_image)
    # and have the profile defined in __create_streamer
```

@abhiTronix ?